# LINQ adding extra logic to the WHERE clause

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Does anybody know why this logic:

```
var t = _repo.Surveys
             .Where(s => s.status && 
                         (s.regionid == null || s.regionid.Value.Equals(regionid)))
             .ToList();
```

would construct this `WHERE` clause ?

```
WHERE ([Extent1].[status] = 1) 
  AND (([Extent1].[regionid] IS NULL) OR 
       (([Extent1].[regionid] = @p__linq__0) AND ( NOT ([Extent1].[regionid] IS NULL OR @p__linq__0 IS NULL))) OR 
       (([Extent1].[regionid] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL)))'
,N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=0
```

I was hoping that it would only compare if the column is null or if it has the value I passed.

Something like:

`WHERE status = 1 AND (regionid IS NULL OR regionid = 0),` for example.

Comment: Looks like an EF auto generated query.  It "tries" to optimize -- try being the key word...  I assume in this case it's looking at a `nullable` property and converting accordingly.

Comment: Did you actually read every comparison? It's doing exactly what you wanted, it's just much more verbose about it.

Comment: @Ellesedil Thanks for your comment. I know it does work...I was just thinking if there's a way to make it cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

You could clean it up a little bit by doing the following:

```
var parameters = new List<Type?>() { null, regionid };
var t = _repo.Surveys
             .Where(s => s.status && parameters.Contains(s.regionid))
             .ToList();
```

*Note replace `Type` with the type of regionid.*

This would generate SQL similar to:

```
WHERE (0 = [Extent1].[Status]) 
  AND ((([Extent1].[RegionId] IN (regionIdValue)) AND ([Extent1].[RegionId] IS NOT NULL)) OR 
       ([Extent1].[RegionId] IS NULL))
```

At that point the only **extra** SQL is the `AND ([Extent1].[RegionId] IS NOT NULL)` condition as part of the IN.

Having said that, the SQL that your original LINQ is generating makes total sense.  The `(NOT ([Extent1].[RegionId] IS NULL OR @p__linq__0 IS NULL))` condition is excluding instances where either the database value is null OR the parameter value is NULL.

Then the `(([Extent1].[regionid] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))` conditions is actually valid in that it is returning values where BOTH the database value and the parameter are null.  In your code you could pass in `null` to the `.Equals` function and it should return that value.

Comment: this will throw a run time error 'system.Type' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as a parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable<T>' you probably want <int?> or were you just using type as a place holder if so you should be more clear on that

Comment: @johnny5 I put Type in there because I didn't know what he was using

Comment: Yeah I figured that out afterwards it seemed like you were using Type which confused me on how you could put an instance in there, and it will even compile because you are using an initializer list